# How does setNeedsLayout work?

Tags: objective-c, delay, setter, nsrunloop, delayed-execution

I would like to know how Apple's `-setNeedsLayout` works.

I already know that it's more efficient than directly calling `-layoutSubviews`, since I might need to do that twice in a method.
And that's just what I need it for: some custom `-setNeedsValidation` for a view controller.
But how to realize such a feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't confirm that Apple does it exactly this way, but here is a way to do what you're looking for, and is likely similar to how `setNeedsLayout` is implemented. I haven't tested this (or even compiled it), but it should give an idea of how to attack the problem as a category on `UIViewController`. Like UIKit, this is completely thread-unsafe.

```
static NSMutableSet sViewControllersNeedingValidation = nil;
static BOOL sWillValidate = NO;

@implementation UIViewController (Validation)
+ (void)load {
  sViewControllersNeedingValidation = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
}

- (void)setNeedsValidation {
  [sViewControllersNeedingValidation addObject:self];

  if (! sWillValidate) {
    sWillValidate = YES;
    // Schedule for the next event loop
    [[self class] performSelector:@selector(dispatchValidation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
  }
}

+ (void)dispatchValidation {
  sWillValidate = NO;
  // The copy here is in case any of the validations call setNeedsValidation.
  NSSet *controllers = [sViewControllersNeedingValidation copy];
  [sViewControllersNeedingValidation removeAllObjects];
  [controllers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(validate)];
  [controllers release];
}

- (void)validate {
  // Empty default implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking out loud... Documentation says that `-setNeedsLayout` schedules layout update in the next "update cycle" (or "drawing update", as mentioned in `-layoutSubviews` docs).

So `-setNeedsLayout` most probably sets a `BOOL` flag. The flag is checked later on (in `-drawRect:`?) and if it's set to `YES`, `-layoutSubviews` is called. Then the flag is cleared and waiting for next calls to `-setNeedsLayout`.

Comment: That's just what I thought. So how do I make a method that gets executed in the next iteration of the main run loop?

Comment: `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with zero delay schedules the selector execution to the run loop.

Comment: Okay, that was obvious. Sorry.